# OpenCV PCA project returning cv::Mat with only 1 column

Tags: opencv, pca

Trying to compress some image descriptors with some difficulties, take this example:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // create some random descriptor 1 rows x 10 cols and populate with some data
    const cv::Mat A = (cv::Mat_<float>(1,10) << 0, -1.5f, -2.f, -3.5f, -3.f, -5.f, -2.f, -2.f, 0, -1.f);
    std::cout << "DESCRIPTOR A : " << std::endl << A << std::endl;

    // create PCA and pass descriptor data with no mean and 6 max components
    cv::PCA pca(A, cv::Mat(), CV_PCA_DATA_AS_ROW, 6);

    // project A to compressed descriptor B (expecting 1 rows x 6 cols)
    const cv::Mat B = pca.project(A);
    std::cout << "DESCRIPTOR B : " << std::endl << B << std::endl;

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Output:

```
DESCRIPTOR A : 
[0, -1.5, -2, -3.5, -3, -5, -2, -2, 0, -1]
DESCRIPTOR B : 
[0]
```

I get that PCA attempts to transform the coordinate system to represent the values with less dimensions, is this done using all the available descriptors? I.e. Does the PCA class need to be constructed with all the descriptors? If so, what if they are unknown?

Note: using OpenCV 3.0.0
Additional Note: in my actual code the descriptor is of dimensions 1 rows x 1000 cols but it is still outputting [0]

Answer (score 0):

The PCA finds a rotation that puts the maximum spread between all samples in the first dimension.

It can't do anything meaningful with one sample alone.

I suggest a visit to the library.

Comment: Ok thanks, obviously don't understand it as I thought I did seems like it is more a machine learning algorithm than just simply a compression algorithm. Thanks anyways.